# How to report a label with 0(zero) when not found in the result in a complex CASE statement

Tags: oracle, case, sqlplus

For reporting purposes I need to create a at first sight very simple report, only creating it is a challenge! Values need to be changed for labels and the number of occurrences of each label need to be counted.

I already created a query that looks to work fine only it doesn't show the label when there are no occurrences.

This is the code I'm using now.

```
COLUMN c1 HEADING "Entity" FORMAT A8
COLUMN c2 HEADING "Quantity" FORMAT 9999999
BREAK ON c1
SELECT (CASE 
         WHEN cat_code = '1234'
          AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                                FROM product_codes
                                              WHERE SUBSTR(prod_code,1,5) != 12345
                                                AND SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6) != 987654
                                             )  
          THEN 'AAA_X'
        WHEN cat_code != '1234'
         AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                               FROM product_codes
                                             WHERE SUBSTR(prod_code,1,5) != 12345
                                               AND SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6) != 987654
                                            )   
          THEN 'AAA_Y'
        WHEN cat_code = '1234'
         AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) NOT IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                                   FROM product_codes
                                                 )  
             THEN 'BBB_X'
        WHEN cat_code != '1234'
         AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) NOT IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                                   FROM product_codes
                                                 )  
             THEN 'BBB_Y'
       END) c1
     , COUNT(*) c2
FROM purchases
WHERE end_time >= '&1'
  AND end_time <  '&2'
GROUP BY (CASE 
         WHEN cat_code = '1234'
          AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                                FROM product_codes
                                              WHERE SUBSTR(prod_code,1,5) != 12345
                                                AND SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6) != 987654
                                             )  
          THEN 'AAA_X'
        WHEN cat_code != '1234'
         AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                               FROM product_codes
                                             WHERE SUBSTR(prod_code,1,5) != 12345
                                               AND SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6) != 987654
                                            )   
          THEN 'AAA_Y'
        WHEN cat_code = '1234'
         AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) NOT IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                                   FROM product_codes
                                                 )  
             THEN 'BBB_X'
        WHEN cat_code != '1234'
         AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) NOT IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                                   FROM product_codes
                                                 )  
             THEN 'BBB_Y'
       END)
ORDER BY 1;
```

For the label BBB_X and BBB_Y there is no data yet in the database which results in no show on the report. The result I'm looking for would be like this example.

```
Entity;Quantity
------ --------
AAA_X ;  123456
AAA_Y ;  654321
BBB_X ;       0
BBB_Y ;       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AAA_X,AAA_Y,BBB_X,BBB_Y` values are derived from some expression and that too constant in your case. so you can achieve the desired output by transferring the logic to aggregate function and using `AAA_X,AAA_Y,BBB_X,BBB_Y` as base data as following:

```
WITH BASE_DATA AS (
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(D,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS C1 FROM
    (SELECT 'AAA_X,AAA_Y,BBB_X,BBB_Y' D FROM DUAL)
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(D,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT b.C1, SUM (CASE 
         WHEN b.C1 = 'AAA_X' AND cat_code = '1234'
          AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                                FROM product_codes
                                              WHERE SUBSTR(prod_code,1,5) != 12345
                                                AND SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6) != 987654
                                             )  
          THEN 1
        WHEN b.C1 = 'AAA_Y' AND cat_code != '1234'
         AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                               FROM product_codes
                                             WHERE SUBSTR(prod_code,1,5) != 12345
                                               AND SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6) != 987654
                                            )   
          THEN 1
        WHEN b.C1 = 'BBB_X' AND cat_code = '1234'
         AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) NOT IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                                   FROM product_codes
                                                 )  
             THEN 1
        WHEN b.C1 = 'BBB_Y' AND cat_code != '1234'
         AND SUBSTR(prod_nbr,1,6) NOT IN (SELECT SUBSTR(prod_code,1,6)
                                                   FROM product_codes
                                                 )  
             THEN 1
       END) c2
    -- , COUNT(*) c2
FROM BASE_DATA b LEFT JOIN purchases p ON (1 = 1)
WHERE end_time >= '&1'
  AND end_time <  '&2'
GROUP BY b.C1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hey Tejash, the did the trick! Thank you very much for sorting this out for me!!! That BASE_DATE part was new for me and will be handy for other queries I have to make. Thanks again.

Comment: Accepted! Where can I found more info about the first part of your answer, the part that starts like WITH BASE_DATA and the used characters?

Comment: Search for CTE(Common table expression)